# php: @fopen works in localhost but not in live server

Tags: php, sftp, fopen

I'm trying to get a remote file like this:

```
$host = 'sftp.hostname.com';
$username = 'user';
$password = '*****';
$port = '22';
$remote_file = 'TOB-20180919.text';
$connection = @ssh2_connect($host, $port);
if ($connection != false) {
    $login = @ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
    if ((bool) $login) {
        $sftp = @ssh2_sftp($connection);
        if ($sftp != false) {
            $stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . "/" . "$remote_file", 'w');
            var_dump($stream);exit;
        }
    }
}
```

`$stream` prints `false` in my live server and `true` in my localhost.
What should I do now?

Comment: remove the quotes around the variable `@fopen("ssh2.sftp://".$sftp . "/" . $remote_file, 'w');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had face same issue so I was solve that type of issue using following code.please use this and check.

put

```
$stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://".(int)$sftp."/".$remote_file, 'w');
```

instead of

```
$stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . "/" . "$remote_file", 'w');
```